# Can oddly not print to stdout after a certain print line?

Tags: c, unix, stdout

Ok, so I was putting in prints to investigate where my program stopped executing, it seems I simply cannot print to stdout after a certain code line, that code line being

```
printf(") : %d\n", PORTNUMBER);
```

Some examples:

```
printf("test1");
printf(") : %d\n", PORTNUMBER);
printf("test2");
```

Prints test1 and the portnumber, but does not print test2.

This:

```
printf(") : %d\n", PORTNUMBER);
fprintf(stdout, "test2");
```

Prints the portnumber, but does not print test2.

This:

```
printf(") : %d\n", PORTNUMBER);
fprintf(stderr, "test2");
```

Prints both the port number and test2.

So my question is, what's going on here, what could be making me unable to write to stdout after the port number print?

Comment: `stdout` may be full of output, so you may not notice the `test2`. Moreover, `stdout` may get blocked somehow, or some file is used instead of `stdout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `stdout`, but not `stderr`, is line-buffered. The C library will buffer your output until it finds a newline, and only then send the complete line to the underlying output.

You'll see that if you replace `"test2"` with `"test2\n"`, it will print as you expect. You can also do `fflush(stdout)` to force `stdout` to flush without a newline.

`stderr`, on the other hand, is unbuffered, which is why output to it will be seen immediately.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and good response, will accept as answer when possible.